# Django email not working - smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected: Connection unexpectedly closed

Tags: python, django, email, sendgrid

I'm using the standard [Django/SendGrid setup](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Frameworks/django.html) for sending emails. Here's the relevant fields in my `settings.py`:

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.sendgrid.net'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'myusername'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'mypassword'
EMAIL_PORT = 465
EMAIL_USE_SSL = True
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'admin@mysite.com'
```

I'm testing sending emails in my shell by executing:

```
send_mail('test','test','email@email.com',['to@email.com'])
```

however, it returns this error Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/app/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/mail/__init__.py", line 62, in send_mail
    return mail.send()
  File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/app/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 348, in send
    return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
  File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/app/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 104, in send_messages
    new_conn_created = self.open()
  File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/app/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 71, in open
    self.connection.login(force_str(self.username), force_str(self.password))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/smtplib.py", line 720, in login
    initial_response_ok=initial_response_ok)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/smtplib.py", line 630, in auth
    (code, resp) = self.docmd("AUTH", mechanism + " " + response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/smtplib.py", line 420, in docmd
    return self.getreply()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/smtplib.py", line 393, in getreply
    raise SMTPServerDisconnected("Connection unexpectedly closed")
smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected: Connection unexpectedly closed
```

Any idea why I'm getting this error?

PS: This is my local development server

Comment: use these configurations and it is working fine for me :
`EMAIL_PORT = 587`
`EMAIL_USE_TLS = True`

Comment: @Zorgan Are you using `django-sendgrid-v5` package to send the emails?

Comment: @ABDULNIYASPM no i am not

Answer (score 5):

## Updated 2021

Sendgrid now requires using [API Key](https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/upgrade-your-authentication-method-to-api-keys/) instead of username/password:

> Two-Factor Authentication is required as of Q4 2020, and all Twilio
> SendGrid API endpoints will reject new API requests and SMTP
> configurations made with a username and password via Basic
> Authentication.

So you'll need to [create an API Key](https://sendgrid.com/docs/ui/account-and-settings/api-keys/#creating-an-api-key) with at least `Mail Send > Full Access` permissions, then tweak your Django configs like this:

```
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'apikey' # this is exactly the value 'apikey'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = SENDGRID_API_KEY
```

[Sample code](https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/django/):

`settings.py`

```
SENDGRID_API_KEY = os.getenv('SENDGRID_API_KEY')

EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.sendgrid.net'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'apikey' # this is exactly the value 'apikey'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = SENDGRID_API_KEY
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

`utils.py`

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail
send_mail('Subject here', 'Here is the message.', 'from@example.com', ['to@example.com'], fail_silently=False)
```

Comment: When I use like this: 
    `EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.sendgrid.net' 
    EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'Xlkdfjdhflkjhfdsklskk'
    EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'SG.Xlkdfjdhflkjhfdsklskk.C_hdgsjhdgdkjfh-8u__fkjdhdfjhfjh5xcv'
    EMAIL_PORT = 587
    EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
    DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'rav@email.co'`

I am getting this error:
Exception Type: SMTPServerDisconnected
Exception Value: Connection unexpectedly closed
What wrong I am doing here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: thanks! I was trying to use the api key id value in `EMAIL_HOST_USER` instead the literal string `'apikey'`

Answer (score 4):

EMAIL_PORT = 465
EMAIL_USE_SSL = True

change this

EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True

and you can check this link
https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/django/

Comment: Another important detail regarding the sendgrid documentation and that went unnoticed by me, regardless of their access credentials, the user will always be apikey (literal): EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'apikey'